# Controlling a mechanical doorbell with an Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino, relay, feedback

I'm trying to control a mechanical doorbell (a small white box with two chimes) using an Arduino UNO. The UNO uses a relay (a 5V relay module something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00XT0OSUQ)) to switch a 12V power supply attached to the doorbell. The Arduino and the 12V side of the relay are powered from the same 1A/12V power supply: the 12V side of the relay is powered directly, and the Arduino is powered through a step-down converter.

Everything works great in theory (running under simulation) and in practice, as long as power isn't connected to the doorbell.

The problem is that when the doorbell is actually powered, triggering the chime resets the Arduino.

I figure there are three possibilities here:

- Feedback from the relay, or
- EM pulse from the doorbell coils when the chime triggers, or
- Voltage drop when the chime triggers

To rule out the feedback issue, I stuck an optocoupler (an FL 817) between the Arduino and the relay. With this in place, I'm still experiencing the problem.

To rule out a voltage drop, I attached a meter to the 5V output of the step-down converter and triggered the chimes. I saw a 0.01 volt drop (from 5.1 volts to 5.09), so that doesn't seem to be the problem, either.

Does this mean it's an EM issue, or could it be something else?

**Update**

Here's a diagram of the major part of the circuit. There is a button, some LEDs, and an input signal from another uC that I haven't shown here.

[image]

Comment: Please, post a diagram of you circuit and if possible some pictures.

Comment: I don't think it is EM. Could you try connecting the system as usual except for the signal that activated the relay module, then use a jumper to drive the _in_ pin on the module manually? Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: How are you powering the relay module? Is is connected directly to the step-down converter?

Comment: attaching a meter won't rule out voltage drop. the drop could be so brief the meter doesn't see it.

but it's probably back-emf from the chimes (assuming the relay module already mitigates back emf from the relay)

Comment: there's no way that an optpcoupler can help you when both devices are sharing the same power supply.  put a diode parallel with the coil of the chimes.

Comment: To second what Jasen suggested, do a quick search for "flyback diode" for more information.

Comment: I've added a circuit diagram. I'm off to read about flyback diodes...